# How to do findstr in batch to search for starting char and ending char

Tags: batch-file

Please help in syntax to do find string to search for a paragrah start with string and end with another string.
Ex: Supporse there is a file with member with id : 1234 is processed successfully . And here i want to search for certain lines starts with  member and end with processed successfully. Here I am using below code(for reference).
Please let me know any confusion into it

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('
findstr /B "member " /E "processed successfully." abc.log
') do set "check=True"
```

Comment: If any answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.

Answer (score 1):

[`Findstr` command](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) using Regular Expressions (Search for patterns of text)

```
 findstr /R "^member\ .*processed\ successfully\.$" abc.log
```

or without Regular Expressions: pipe `findstr` output to another `findstr` as follows:

```
 findstr /B /C:"member " abc.log | findstr /E /C:"processed successfully."
```

**Note**: you need to escape the `|` pipe character if used in [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)  against the results of piped commands as follows:

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('
     findstr /B /C:"member " abc.log ^| findstr /E /C:"processed successfully."
') do set "check=True"
```

> **Regular Expressions**: `FINDSTR` support for regular expressions is limited and non-standard, only the following metacharacters are
>   supported:
>
> ```
>  .         Wildcard: any character
>
>  *         Repeat: zero or more occurances of previous character or class
>
>  ^         Line position: beginning of line
>  $         Line position: end of line
>
>  [class]   Character class: any one character in set
>  [^class]  Inverse class: any one character not in set
>
>  [x-y]     Range: any characters within the specified range
>
>  \x        Escape: literal use of metacharacter x
>
>  \<xyz     Word position: beginning of
>  xyz\>     Word position: end of word
> ```

Comment: @ Josef, Thanks  for you prompt response.                                                                                                    But when i am using the same its not working as below :                                                                                    for /f "delims=" %%A in ('
findstr /B /C:"member" abc.txt ^| findstr /E /C:"processed successfully." abc.txt 
') do set "check=True"

echo Variable : %Check%

Comment: @saurabh read carefully: there should be no file specification in second (piped to) `findstr` as it should search in first (piped from) `findstr` output. Moreover, consider whether or not a `/I` switch (force case-insensitive search) should be used.